# iterator for dates in python

Tags: python, date, iterator

I have a begin_date `datetime.date(2012, 9, 1)` and an end_date `datetime.date(2012, 9, 30)`

I would like get a iterator or a list which includes dates 2012/9/1 to 2012/9/30. Is any way other then a loop do make that iterator or list

Comment: No, you'll need a loop -- But you can bury the loop in a function/generator so you never have to see it again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without a implicit loop you can do:

```
from datetime import date
from dateutil.rrule import rrule, DAILY

iterdates=iter(rrule(DAILY, dtstart=date(2012, 9, 1), until=date(2012, 9, 30)))
```

Answer (score 10):

Use a generator:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

def dategenerator(start, end):
    current = start
    while current <= end:
        yield current
        current += timedelta(days=1)
```

Demo:

```
>>> for dt in dategenerator(date(2012, 9, 1), date(2012, 9, 30)):
...     print dt
... 
2012-09-01
2012-09-02
2012-09-03
2012-09-04
2012-09-05
2012-09-06
2012-09-07
2012-09-08
2012-09-09
2012-09-10
2012-09-11
2012-09-12
2012-09-13
2012-09-14
2012-09-15
2012-09-16
2012-09-17
2012-09-18
2012-09-19
2012-09-20
2012-09-21
2012-09-22
2012-09-23
2012-09-24
2012-09-25
2012-09-26
2012-09-27
2012-09-28
2012-09-29
2012-09-30
```

Comment: Obligatory +1 required by law in every Martijn Pieters `python` answer :-P